# choppy animation with glmark2

Tags: 13.10, graphics, radeon

I just installed ubuntu and currently I am suffering from poor graphics performance.

I ran `glmark2` to test graphics and while it prints a good fps in console, it does not feel so. Animation is not smooth it is choppy.

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2012.08
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     X.Org
    GL_RENDERER:   Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV630
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 9.2.1
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 54 FrameTime: 18.519 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 64 FrameTime: 15.625 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 58 FrameTime: 17.241 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 66 FrameTime: 15.152 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 59 FrameTime: 16.949 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 62 FrameTime: 16.129 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 59 FrameTime: 16.949 ms
[shading] shading=phong: FPS: 61 FrameTime: 16.393 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly: FPS: 55 FrameTime: 18.182 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals: FPS: 66 FrameTime: 15.152 ms
[bump] bump-render=height: FPS: 55 FrameTime: 18.182 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;: FPS: 32 FrameTime: 31.250 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;: FPS: 16 FrameTime: 62.500 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false: FPS: 63 FrameTime: 15.873 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4: FPS: 19 FrameTime: 52.632 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4: FPS: 33 FrameTime: 30.303 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 41 FrameTime: 24.390 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata: FPS: 41 FrameTime: 24.390 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=true:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 42 FrameTime: 23.810 ms
[ideas] speed=duration: FPS: 45 FrameTime: 22.222 ms
[jellyfish] <default>: FPS: 40 FrameTime: 25.000 ms
[terrain] <default>: FPS: 7 FrameTime: 142.857 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 59 FrameTime: 16.949 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 52 FrameTime: 19.231 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 60 FrameTime: 16.667 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 61 FrameTime: 16.393 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 51 FrameTime: 19.608 ms
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 60 FrameTime: 16.667 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 61 FrameTime: 16.393 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 46 FrameTime: 21.739 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 49 
=======================================================
```

Why even with good fps animation is so poor? how could I further diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install original drivers from manufactor of your video adapter: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Comment: There are no original drivers from amd for 13.10. There is amd beta driver http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx, but they do not support my videocard